# How to check response from the RestTemplate for error and success case for the JSON String?

Tags: java, json, resttemplate

I am working on a project in which I am making a rest url call to my servers which gives me back a JSON String as a response. If there are any problems with the service then it will give me either of these below JSON String as the response -

```
{"error":"no user_id passed"}

or

{"warning": "user_id not found", "user_id": some_user_id}

or

{"error": "user_id for wrong partition", "user_id": some_user_id, "partition": some_partition}

or

{"error":"no client_id passed"}

or

{"error": "missing client id", "client_id":2000}
```

Below is my code  by which I am making a call and here `response` variable will have above JSON string if something has gone wrong on the service side but if it is a success response, then it won't contain any of the above JSON String. It will be a valid JSON String with a proper data but JSON String for success response is totally different as compared to above error case JSON String so I cannot have a same POJO for that..

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

// check response here as it will have above error JSON String if 
// something has gone wrong on the server side, and some other data if it is a success
```

And I need to log an error if response contains any of the above JSON String as it's an error but if it doesn't contain the above JSON String, then log as a success..

NOTE: If the response from the service is not success, then it will have error and warning as the first key in the JSON String.. But if it is a success, then it will proper data in the JSON String..

What is the easiest and efficient way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works if you return different response when it is successful and it doesn't include key "error".

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
bool isError = false;

//I checke for one error you can do same for other errors and warning as well. You can directly check this from array.
if(jsonObject.has("error"))
{
    String error = jsonObject.getString("error");
    if(errror == "no user_id passed")
     {
        isError = true;
     }
}

if(!isError)
{
  //continue what you were doing.
}
```

Comment: Suppose for whatever reason, error is also contain in the actual success data, then how would I tackle this situation? But one thing to note here is success data won't be starting with error or warning..

Comment: then I fear you won't be able to check it this way unless you have the list of errors. if you have the list of errors then you can compare here.

Comment: All my error is shown in above question.. Those are the only error I am going to get..

Answer (score 0):

You can use "has" method of JSONObject from org.json library to check if a particular key is present in your json string. You can use this method to check if error is returned by your server and process accordingly.

Example code:

```
//Array of all errors
String[] error_list = ["no user_id passed","user_id not found","user_id for wrong partition","no client_id passed"];
public boolean isErrorResp(String json_response)
{
   try
   {
     JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(json_response); //create JSONObject for your response

     //check if your response has "error" key if so check if the value of error key is in the error_list array
     if(json_obj.has("error")&&Arrays.asList(error_list).contains(json_obj.getString("error")))
     {

       return true; 
     }
     else if(json_obj.has("warning")&&Arrays.asList(error_list).contains(json_obj.getString("warning")))
     {
          return true;
     };

     return false;
   }
   catch(JSONException ex)
   {
   //error handling for improper json string.
     return false;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @hermanth If the JSON is invalid, your method does not return.

Comment: WHat does has method do? it will check the key of the JSON String ?

Comment: @ssh it will check if a particular key is present in the JSONObject or not